# What's the meaning of "certain issues of conscience"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> On **certain issues of conscience**, she refused to take a partisan stand.

What does "certain issues of conscience" mean?

I know meanings of the words- 'certain', 'issue', and 'conscience',but I'm not sure about the meaning of this combination.

I guess it is somewhat related to conscience vote in which you vote according
to your personal conscience rather than according to the official line set 
by the party.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscience_vote

Comment: I think you get the general idea exactly right! However, because you're not sure, it's possible that you get the meaning of each word wrong. Would you consider sharing with us the meanings of 'certain', 'issue', and 'conscience'?

Comment: Examples of issues of conscience: abortion; euthanasia; gay marriage; the death penalty; military conscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these words have multiple meanings, so to reword the phrase in this context:

"Certain" means "some."
"Issues" means "matters."
"Conscience" means "personal conviction or belief."

Therefore the sentence means: "In some (but not all) matters of personal beliefs, she refused to take a partisan stand."